How do I print out the Linq values, that have been added to a List, instead of: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" in C#?
I am making a Three Or More game, which means that I need to make the programme recognise repeated values (for a 3 of a kind function).
I have created a Die class that rolls a pseudorandom integer from 1-6:
internal class Die
{
    private static Random random = new Random(); // Creates an instance of a random object using the built-in Random class

    // Roll() method
    public int Roll()
    {
        int diceroll = random.Next(1, 7); // Picks a random integer (1-6) from a list using the random object

        //Console.WriteLine("One dice rolled a "+ diceroll);

        return diceroll; // Assigns a value to the dicevalue property
    }
}

In my Game class, and then in my ThreeOrMore class, I've created an empty list:
List<int> player1dicerolls = new List<int>();

The for loop is then used to roll the player's dice 5 times, by creating a Die object, and then adds the dice roll to the List:
               for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
               {
                   Die dice1 = new Die();
                   int x = dice1.Roll();
                   Console.ReadLine();
                   Console.WriteLine($"One dice rolled a {x}");
                   player1dicerolls.Add(x);
               }

And finally, I have used a foreach statement to print out each value of the List, which are then put through a Linq (which should print out the dice numbers that are repeated):
An overflow answer said to try "string.Join()", however that hasn't worked either.
                foreach (var value in player1dicerolls.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
                    .ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(player1dicerolls);
                }

                string.Join(", ", player1dicerolls);

However, my output is this:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Can anyone please help me make the programme print out the repeated values?

So you create a list (player1dicerolls.some_linq.ToList()), iterate it storing each individual item of the iteration in var value. You almost got it. You should print value.Element and/or value.Counter instead of Console.WriteLine(player1dicerolls);

player1dicerolls is your original List<int>. The items of the LINQ result are assigned to the loop variable value. The .ToList() at the end of the LINQ is superfluous. Without it the query will yield an IEnumerable<T> which can be iterated directly by foreach.

Let's solve your problem with a help of Linq, we should

group player1dicerolls by scores
filter out groups with just one item
let's order the groups by score
represent each group in Element: Counter: format
finally, join these representation with, say, new line delimiter

For instance:
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, player1dicerolls
  .GroupBy(score => score)
  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
  .OrderBy(group => group.Key) 
  .Select(group => $"Element: {group.Key}, Counter: {group.Count()}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);


Thank you both so much for the help and feedback, It's all sorted now! Would you be able to upvote my question if possible? (stack overflow has warned that I will never be ale to ask any more questions, unless i recieve upvotes, because of my past questions) Thanks.

Let me declutter your last code snippet:
//If you anonymous type was a tuple, the full typing will be `List<(int Element, int Counter)>`
var repeatedRolls = player1dicerolls
    .GroupBy(id => id)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => new 
    { 
        Element = group.Key, 
        Counter = group.Count() 
    })
    .ToList(); //Be mindful that is is *not* lazy since `.ToList()` is used here

foreach ((int Element, int Counter) value in repeatedRolls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); //We want to see the current element being iterated, not the collection
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", player1dicerolls)); //forgot `Console.WriteLine()` here

The entire issue really is just misuse of your variables and forgetting to apply certain things like Console.WriteLine(). string.Join() will return you a string, it will not print directly to console for you. Nothing does that except for the dedicated Console library methods
Lastly, a small note here on .ToList(): this specific snippet does qualify for use of lazy iteration, as you are only going to iterate and read the current element. This means that your iteration will execute 2 times (for loop + the string join) rather than 3 times (eager evaluation of the list, then the for loop, then the string join). It allows C# to wait and defer the execution until it is forced to do so
//If you anonymous type was a tuple, the full typing will be `IEnumerable<(int Element, int Counter)>`
var repeatedRolls = player1dicerolls
    .GroupBy(id => id)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => new 
    { 
        Element = group.Key, 
        Counter = group.Count() 
    }); //NOTHING ACTUALLY HAPPENS IN MEMORY, we are just defining the query. Imagine this is like a SQL stored procedure

//1ST ITERATION
foreach ((int Element, int Counter) value in repeatedRolls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

//2ND ITERATION
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", player1dicerolls));

Note: I am using a tuple in place of your anonymous object, but this may very well become a struct, record, etc etc. My key point is to highlight that a List is a classic collection that forces evaluation, while IEnumerable allows for deferred execution

The result will be an IEnumerable<a> where a is the anonymous type with the Element and Counter fields. You can't assign it to a List<int> and since this type has no name you must use var repeatedRolls = player1dicerolls.LinqQuery();

@OlivierJacot-Descombes my mistake, thank you for the catch. I wanted to include the full written types to highlight the difference between a "classic" vs lazy collection. I quickly assumed List<int> because of the error message. I will update my answer accordingly

For the sake of readability, I have "interpreted" the anon type into a tuple within the clarifying comments. The code itself still maintains use of an anonymous type. If this is at all confusing, prefer to use a tuple, struct, record, etc instead of anon typing. With the newer dotnet versions they are very simple to declare and use

@Dmitry Bychenko I am now using your code, Thanks for all the help. I'm now trying to use the Linq's output (so the rolls which have been repeated) into an if statement. Eg. "if the number is repeated twice: (double the player's score). I am really struggling to implement this, as the Linq's output does not really support this. Can you help?

You are trying to deconstruct anonymous types. This feature has been discussed here but I don't think it was implemented. You could create a tuple in the first place instead of an anonymous type.

@MaxButler as in changing the where clause to .Where(group => group.Count() == 2) ? This will grab all those item-groups with exactly two count

@Narish Yes I have now done what you have said, now I just want to convert the result of the query into a new variable (so that if the query prints out any 2 of a kinds, an if statement will recognise this (and eg. print something out)).

@MaxButler I'm not sure what you envision, maybe alter the final select to produce the string representations you want, resulting in IEnumerable .Select(group => group.Count() == 2 ? $"Two of {group.Key}" : $"Any count of {group.Key}"). Notice the use of ternary operator to get it onelined
